# Freezes during while loop in simple menu code

Tags: c, loops

I'm trying to write a simple text menu, the code compiles fine but execution freezes as it enters the while loop and no code inside the loop is executed. The code is very simple and I can't see the problem.

```
void menu()
{
    int option = 1;
    while (option!=3);
    {
        printf("Select an option\n\n");
        printf("1. Input data\n");
        printf("2. View table of data\n");
        printf("3. Exit program\n");
        scanf("%d", &option);


        switch (option)
        {
            case 1:
            printf("Inputting data\n");
            break;

            case 2:
            printf("Viewing table\n");
            break;

            default:
            printf("Invalid choice, please try again\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.


Comment: And [we close all typo questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have  a stray semicolon

```
while (option!=3);
                ^^^
```

This will loop forever.

Try this instead

```
while (option!=3)
                ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that. Accepting the answer when it allows me to.

Comment: @Dawson; You can accept the answer now. Just click the V mark just below the vote count.

Comment: @haccks Patience. One cannot accept an answer for 15 minutes, you have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(option!=3);
```

this just is an infinite loop
correct the code to remove semi-colon
and also ask user to input value 3 to exit else it will not exit from while loop as 3 will never get entered.